# Edit binary plist under linux

Tags: iphone, linux, perl, macos, plist

How can i change values in the binary plist under linux os?
I know i can to it under mac with defaults or PlistBuddy.
I found some perl that convert from binary to text [Mac::PropertyList::ReadBinary](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Mac-PropertyList-1.33/lib/ReadBinary.pm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert to xml, and edit that version. I'm unaware of any Mac app that will reject plists in xml formats.

If for some reason you insist on editing the binary representation, the format is documented in several places, eg: https://quaqua.dev.java.net/source/browse/quaqua/trunk/Quaqua/src/ch/randelshofer/quaqua/util/BinaryPListParser.java?view=markup

Comment: Great,thanks
I'll convert to xml
I didn't know that i can work with xml after compilation.